# Moq an object in a static class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I can't get Moq to mock an object that gets created in a static method.
Here is my moq and code

code:

```
public interface IConfigHelper
{
    string GetConfiguration(string sectionName, string elementName);
}

public class ConfigHelper : IConfigHelper
{
    public ConfigHelper() { }

    public virtual string GetConfiguration(string sectionName, string elementName)
    {
        string retValue = String.Empty;
        //Does things to get configuration and return a value    
        return retValue;
    }
}

public class myRealClass
{
    public myRealClass(){}
    public string myworkingMethod()
    {
        var retValue = String.Empty;
        retValue = utilSvc.GetConfigurationValue();
        return retValue;
    }
}

public static class utilSvc
{
    public static string GetConfigurationValue()
    {
        ConfigHelper configUtil = new ConfigHelper(); //NOT BEING MOCKED
        return configUtil.GetConfiguration("sectionName/sectionElement", "ClinicalSystem");
    }
}
```

the Test using Moq

```
[TestFixture(TestName = "Tests")]
public class Tests 
{
    private Mock<IConfigHelper> configHelperMOCK;
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        configHelperMOCK = new Mock<IConfigHelper>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void serviceIsBPManagementForValidSource()
    {
        //Arrange
        string sectionName = "sectionName/sectionElement";
        string clinicalElementName = "ClinicalSystem";
        string clinicalElementValue = "Zedmed";
        configHelperMOCK.Setup(s => s.GetConfiguration(sectionName, clinicalElementName)).Returns(clinicalElementValue);

        //act
        // the call to myRealClass

        //assert
        // test assertions
    }
}
```

The issue that I am having is with this line:

```
ConfigHelper configUtil = new ConfigHelper(); //NOT BEING MOCKED
```

I cannot get the moq to Mock the object. 
I do not want the code to read the config file. I wish to moq away this instance of `ConfigHelper`

Answer (score 1):

Avoid coupling your code to static classes, which in most cases cause you code be to difficult to maintain and test.

Follow the [Explicit Dependencies Principle](http://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/)

> Methods and classes should explicitly require (typically through
>   method parameters or constructor parameters) any collaborating objects
>   they need in order to function correctly.

Give the article a read. It is short and very informative.

If you want to keep the static class then you wrap the static class behind an abstraction.

```
public interface IUtilSvc {
    string GetConfigurationValue();
}

public class utilSvcWrapper : IUtilSvc {
    public string GetConfigurationValue() {
        return utilSvc.GetConfigurationValue(); //Calling static service
    }
}
```

Or another option is that utlSvc does not have to be static if can be injected into dependent classes

```
public class utilSvc : IUtilScv {
    private readonly IConfigHelper configUtil;

    public utilSvc(IConfigHelper configHelper) {
        configUtil = configHelper;
    }

    public string GetConfigurationValue() {
        return configUtil.GetConfiguration("sectionName/sectionElement", "ClinicalSystem");
    }
}
```

Inject the `IUtilScv` into the dependent class so that it is no longer dependent on static class.

```
public class myRealClass {
    private readonly IUtilScv utilSvc;

    //Explicit dependency inject via constructor
    public myRealClass(IUtilScv utilSvc) {
        this.utilSvc = utilSvc;
    }

    public string myworkingMethod() {
        var retValue = utilSvc.GetConfiguration();
        return retValue;
    }
}
```

In that case you don't even need `IConfigHelper` when testing as it has also been abstracted away. And you only need to mock the dependencies needed for the test.

```
[TestFixture(TestName = "Tests")]
public class Tests {
    private Mock<IUtilScv> utilScvMOCK;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup() {
        utilScvMOCK = new Mock<IUtilScv>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void serviceIsBPManagementForValidSource() {
        //Arrange
        var expectedClinicalElementValue = "Zedmed";
        utilScvMOCK
            .Setup(s => s.GetConfiguration())
            .Returns(expectedClinicalElementValue)
            .Verifiable();            

        var sut = new myRealClass(utilScvMOCK.Object);

        //Act
        var actualClinicalElementValue = sut.myworkingMethod();

        //Assert
        configHelperMOCK.Verify();
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedClinicalElementValue, actualClinicalElementValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand, follow and use the Explicit Dependencies Principle. but ConfigHelper is NOT a dependency of myRealClass. It is a dependency on utilSvc. The method in utilSvc is static as it is a method used by Ninject's Bind<>().WithConstructorArgument, which has to be static

Comment: I can't wrap the static class/method, as it must be called by Ninject's Bind<>().WithConstructorArgument. That requires a static method. it is from that static method I am creating a ConfigHelper which reads the config. I want to mock the ConfigHelper

Answer (score 1):

You can't wrap the static class/method but you can redirect it

```
public static class UtilSvc
{
     static UtilSvc()
     {
         CreatorFunc = () => new ConfigHelper();
     }

     public static Func<IConfigHelper> CreatorFunc { get; set; }

     public static string GetConfigurationValue()
     {
         var configUtil = CreatorFunc();
         return configUtil.GetConfiguration("sectionName/sectionElement", 
                                            "ClinicalSystem");
     }
}
```

and then in the test

```
//...
private Mock<IConfigHelper> configHelperMOCK;

[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    configHelperMOCK = new Mock<IConfigHelper>();
    UtilService.CreatorFunc = () => configHelperMOCK.Object;
}
//...
```

Comment: My bad on the object. Will update. Not too sure  about the interface comment though. If UtilSvc.GetConfigurationValue() gets called, this should return the mock instance instead of a new-ed one. What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks. The problem with doing this on a phone not in an IDE :?

Comment: Yep, it should be Func<IConfigHelper>. Changed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock static class. I would rather propose to inject that `IConfigHelper` into the `myRealClass`. That is the usual way how to decouple dependencies and use DI.

```
public class myRealClass
{
  private IConfigHelper _configHelper;  

  public myRealClass(IConfigHelper configHelper)
  {
     _configHelper = configHelper;
  }

  public string myworkingMethod()
  {
     var retValue = String.Empty;
     retValue = _configHelper.GetConfigurationValue();
     return retValue;
   }
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to mock a static class! I am trying to mock a class that is created inside a static method. The method is static as it is a method used by Ninject's Bind<>().WithConstructorArgument, which has to be static.

Comment: You should still inject the object. Also ensure you're running your tests without parallelism, many test runners runs tests side-by-side and this is not safe when you're involving static classes.

Comment: Also, in terms of the class being static, it can often pay off to make it into a singleton instead, thus you can still instantiate instances for test while having a static single instance available for the program.